# Why use path.join() instead of just static('public')

Tags: node.js, express

In all the node express tutorials I've read the following syntax is used to create the public directory:

```
var path = require('path');
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')))
```

However the following works just fine:

```
app.use(express.static('public'))
```

So why would I use the path module instead ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The last example uses a relative path, which will work if you start your app from the directory that has `public` as a subdirectory.

However, it will break if you start your app from another directory. Let's assume that your app is located in `/path/to/app/directory` but that you start your script while `/tmp` is the current (working) directory:

```
/tmp$ node /path/to/app/directory/app.js
```

In that situation, Express will try to use `/tmp/public` as the location for your static files, which isn't correct.

Using `path.join(__dirname, 'public')` will create an absolute path, using the directory where `app.js` is located as the base. In the example above, it will resolve to `/path/to/app/directory/public`, which will also be valid if you start your script from another working directory.